# Getting the default Divider in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I found some guides online, using Java, that attempt to get the default `Drawable` `listDivider` from android.

After converting the code to Kotlin I have the following;

```
val attrs = IntArray(android.R.attr.listDivider)
val ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs)
mDivider = ta.getDrawable(0)
ta.recycle()
```

But I run into an out of memory exception and the application closes.

I have tried inspecting `android.R.attr.listDivider` and its just a list of lot of 0's and `R.attr.listDivider` doesn't exist (I have `R` imported).

Not really sure what else I can try.

Edit: I get the feeling that it might have something to do with themes. Here is the setup for the themes, I only use a single activity in my application, everything is done with fragments.

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Then in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

EDIT2; I have also created a new application that just runs the code block and I get the same `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 404238828 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 318MB until OOM` error

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. Keep in mind, it's pulling whatever the divider drawable is from the current theme for the context. If your theme is `AppCompat`, the `listDivider` is defined as null because AppCompat doesn't use them.

Comment: @Tenfour04, I updated the post to include the Theme. I'm confused about `AppCompat` not using them because `val itemDecoration: RecyclerView.ItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)` does display a divider when I use it in code. What reference should I be getting for the default divider?

Comment: It's so complicated to follow through the whole theme setup, I'm not sure. I can't find any place where it's set to anything besides null. It looks like DividerItemDecoration's constructor uses the same code as what you're using and warns you if `android.R.attr.listDivider`is producing null for the current theme. You could try `val attrs = IntArray(R.attr.dividerVertical)`. That seems to be indirectly referenced from other places in AppCompat.

Comment: Thanks for trying, still get the MemoryError...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was initializing the `IntArray` wrong;

```
val attrs = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.listDivider)
val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs)
mDivider = a.getDrawable(0)
a.recycle()
```